# Mapping CSV Header using a Dictionary

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dictionary, header

I have a reference file that looks like this:

```
Experiment,Array,Drug
8983,Genechip,Famotidine
8878,Microarray,Dicyclomine
8988,Genechip,Etidronate
8981,Microarray,Flunarizine
```

I successfully created a dictionary mapping the `Experiment` numbers to the `Drug` name using the following:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('C:\Users\Troy\Documents\ExPSRef.txt'))
#Configure dictionary
result = {}
for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    result[key] = row[2]
di = result
```

I want to map this dictionary to the header of another file which consists of the experiment number. It currently looks like this:

```
Gene,8988,8981,8878,8983
Vcp,0.011,-0.018,-0.032,-0.034
Ube2d2,0.034,0.225,-0.402,0.418
Becn1,0.145,-0.108,-0.421,-0.048
Lypla2,-0.146,-0.026,-0.101,-0.011
```

But it should look like this:

```
Gene,Etidronate,Flunarizine,Dicyclomine,Famotidine
Vcp,0.011,-0.018,-0.032,-0.034
Ube2d2,0.034,0.225,-0.402,0.418
Becn1,0.145,-0.108,-0.421,-0.048
Lypla2,-0.146,-0.026,-0.101,-0.011
```

I tried using:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

reader = csv.reader(open('C:\Users\Troy\Documents\ExPSRef.txt'))
result = {}
    for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    result[key] = row[2]
    di = result
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Troy\Documents\ExPS2.txt')
df['row[0]'].replace(di, inplace=True)
```

but it returned a `KeyError: 'row[0]'`.

I tried the following as well, even transposing in order to merge:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Troy\Documents\ExPS2.txt',).transpose()
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Troy\Documents\ExPSRef.txt', delimiter=',', engine='python')
df3 = df1.merge(df2)
df4 = df3.set_index('Drug').drop(['Experiment', 'Array'], axis=1)
df4.index.name = 'Drug'
print df4
```

and this time received `MergeError('No common columns to perform merge on')`.

Is there a simpler way to map my dictionary to the header that would work?

Comment: can you show the code you used when you attempted to replace the headers, other than just the one line

Comment: Hey @Navidad20, I edited it in above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things to keep in mind would be to making sure that both the `keys` corresponding to the mapper dictionary as well as the header which it is mapped to are of the same data type.

Here, one is a string and the other of integer type. So while reading itself, we'll let it not interpret `dtype` by setting it to `str` for the reference `DF`.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Troy\Documents\ExPS2.txt')               # Original
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Troy\Documents\ExPSRef.txt', dtype=str)  # Reference
```

Convert the columns of the original `DF` to it's series representation and then replace the old value which were *Experiment Nos.* with the new *Drug name* retrieved from the reference `DF`.

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.to_series().replace(df2.set_index('Experiment').Drug)
df1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used `csv` for the whole script. This fixes the header you wanted and saves into a new file. The new filename can be replaced with the same one if that's what you prefer. This program is written with python3.

```
import csv 

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as ref:
    reader = csv.reader(ref)
    # skip header line
    next(reader)
    # make dictionary
    di = dict([(row[0], row[2]) for row in reader])

data = []
with open('sample1.txt', 'r') as df:
    reader = csv.reader(df)
    header = next(reader)
    new_header = [header[0]] + [di[i] for i in header if i in di]
    data = list(reader)

# used to make new file, can also replace with the same file name
with open('new_sample1.txt', 'w') as df_new:
    writer = csv.writer(df_new)
    writer.writerow(new_header)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: I was able to successfully use @Nickil Maveli's script to solely use pandas.  This though, does work as well as a csv script. Thanks!!